# CSS color property works on some computers, but not others

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have boxes where some have a yellow background with black writing, and others have blue background with white writing. This seems to work in Google Chrome on all computers; however, it only works in IE sometimes. I currently have IE11 and it seems to work perfectly fine (when not in compatibility mode). On another computer with IE11, it shows a grey font on both the yellow and blue boxes. But with compatibility viewer, all boxes are yellow with black font. On a third computer, it shows all the boxes as yellow with black font.

The only problem is the grey font on the yellow and blue because it makes it hard to read.
Any suggestions?

Here is my code to make all elements yellow with black text:

```
ul.testimonials li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
  background:#ffc;
  display:block;
}
```

Here is my code to make every other element blue with white text:

```
ul.testimonials li:nth-child(even) a{
 background:#4F4FBB;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

I'm not sure where the grey color is coming from. There are other style sheets embedded into the page, but I cannot find where the grey is being set. Also, I thought that css was done locally, so if I set a property directly in this html, it would override any stylesheets. Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks for any help you may provide!

**edited:** I do see in the stylesheet that the body is set to a grey color, also it says

```
#content p big a {
    color: #666;
}
```

may that be the problem? Why does my CSS not override this?

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="testimonials">
 <li>
 <a href="#">
  <p>TEXT 1<br><br><p style="text-align:right"><b>INSERT NAME HERE</b></p></p>
 </a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a href="#">
  <p>TEXT 2<br><br><p style="text-align:right"><b>INSERT NAME HERE</b></p></p>
 </a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a href="#">
  <p>TEXT 3<br><br><p style="text-align:right"><b>INSERT NAME HERE</b></p></p>
 </a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a href="#">
  <p>TEXT 4<br><br><p style="text-align:right"><b>INSERT NAME HERE</b></p></p>
 </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That "compatibility view" downgrades IE11 to render like IE7, and IE7 didn't recognize three-digit color values or `rgba()` either, or actually almost nothing you've in your style rules.

Comment: Use the inspector. It will tell you where the gray comes from. It is also a link, so check if you have a:hover or a:visited changing the color.

Comment: Show the relevant HTML too. Try to remove those parts of CSS code that are not relevant to the problem. Clearly state exactly where the problem can be seen, referring to specific HTML elements.

Comment: is an inspector similar to the debugger? @Ann

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I have edited the question to be more clear. The problem is seen in IE11 on one computer (not another) where the boxes are alternating yellow/blue, but all text is in grey. Then, in compatibility mode on that same computer, all text is black on a yellow background.

Comment: The code posted still doesn’t produce the problem. There is nothing in it that sets anything gray. The added CSS code does not apply to anything in the HTML code.

Comment: @ChellyS Is there a reason you're putting this page into a compatibility mode? That is usually meant for sites designed in *older* versions of IE, which doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: That property applying the grey color has an ID selector. ID's have higher specificity than the class selectors in your CSS, hence why you aren't overriding it. Either use an ID as well, or throw an !important and it'll probably override.

Comment: did u try after clearing a browser cache? Ctrl+F5....